# How to inject my AddDbContext<ContainerContext> into my DAL project (Core 3.1)

Tags: .net-core, dependency-injection, database-connection

I'm using MVC 5, Core 3.1

I have 'AddDbContext' added to my service in Startup.cs.

I then have a Class library core 3.1 project which is my ADO Dal layer.
This is added as a service as well in The ConfigureServices of Startup.cs.

I want to inject the Connection String into the DAL application.

I have:

```
public partial class ContainerContext : DbContext
{
    public ContainerContext()
    {
    }

    public ContainerContext(DbContextOptions<ContainerContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

In Startup.cs

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var connection = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        services.AddDbContext<ContainerContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

        services.AddDAL();
    }
```

In the Dal project:

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    // Add parameters if required, e.g. for configuration
    public static IServiceCollection AddDAL(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Register all services as required
        services.AddScoped<ILeaseBll, LeaseDal>();

        return services;
    }
}
```

The Dal class.

```
public class LeaseDal :  ILeaseBll 
{

    private string conString;

    public LeaseDal(???????)
    {
        // Some validation for the Context maybe (isNull etc?) throw new ArgumentNullException("conString");
        //this.connectionString = conString;
    }
```

How would / should it be done?
Thanks

Comment: do you need dbcontext or connectionstring in LeaseDal class. if you need connection string then you can inject IConfiguration in the ctor of LeaseDal and get the connection string.

Comment: @CodingMytra I need the connection string in the Dal class. I don't know what ctor is however (in your comment) Are you saying I need private IConfiguration in my LeaseClass (dal) (tried that but that has compile error).. this is all new to me, apologies

Comment: and why do need connection string in your LeaseDal class, are you making connection yourself ? and not using entityframework in this library.

Comment: Using Ado.net , no EF at

Comment: if you are not using EF then why do you have `ContainerContext` in your code ?

Comment: I agree with CodingMytra.  "ContainerContext : DbContext" .. that is entity-framework-core.  The object full name is "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore. DbContext" ..   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext?view=efcore-6.0

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, re entity-framework-core and dbContext.  I am new to Core and it's DI. I used Ninject prior to the move to Core. So, guess the error is on my side. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

There is a philosophy change with Dot-Net-Core and Dot-Net-Framework....

```
public class LeaseDal :  ILeaseBll 
{

    private string conString;
```

This is not best practice in dot-net-CORE.

You do NOT inject your "connection string" in your concrete DataAccessLayer object.

You inject the db-context.

(and the db-context already has been wired to the Ioc...with its correct connection string)

Something like this:

```
public interface IDepartmentQueryDomainData()
{
    Task<int> GetCountAsync(CancellationToken token);
}
```

..

```
public class DepartmentQueryEntityFrameworkDomainDataLayer : IDepartmentQueryDomainData
{
    public const string ErrorMessageILoggerFactoryIsNull = "ILoggerFactory is null";

    public const string ErrorMessageMyCoolDbContextIsNull =
        "MyCoolDbContext is null";


    private readonly ILogger<DepartmentQueryEntityFrameworkDomainDataLayer> logger;

    private readonly MyCoolDbContext entityDbContext;


    public DepartmentQueryEntityFrameworkDomainDataLayer(
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        MyCoolDbContext context
    {
        if (null == loggerFactory)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(ErrorMessageILoggerFactoryIsNull, (Exception)null);
        }

        this.logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<DepartmentQueryEntityFrameworkDomainDataLayer>();


        this.entityDbContext = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(
            ErrorMessageMyCoolDbContextIsNull,
            (Exception)null);

    }

    public async Task<int> GetCountAsync(CancellationToken token)
    {
        int returnValue = await this.entityDbContext.Departments.AsNoTracking().CountAsync(token);
        this.logger.Log(
            new LogEntry(
                LoggingEventTypeEnum.Trace,
                string.Format(
                    LogMessages.Count,
                    returnValue)));
        return returnValue;
    }

}
```

You can also "see" this here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/

```
public class MyController
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public MyController(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
}
```

I would never inject the dbContext into a "controller"...(I agree with you that the Dal should be a separate layer)...
but besides that "miscue" on the microsoft example, you do see that you inject the dbContext.

Also see:

https://hovermind.com/aspnet-core/using-dbcontext-with-dependency-injection.html